# Copying data with images from Word, and pasting said data with images in Internet Explorer fails to paste images

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Here is the Technical information about software being used:

- Internet Explorer 11
- Microsoft Word 2013 (15.0.4875.1000) MSO 32-bit
- Windows 7 Professional 64-bit (Service Pack 1)

I was trying to copy data with images from Microsoft Word and paste it into a fill-in form on a webpage in Internet Explorer.

image of menu shown in Internet Explorer when you right-click on fill-in form entry box:

[image: image of menu shown in Internet Explorer when you right-click on fill-in form entry box]

However, the text were pasted over successfully, however, the images failed to get pasted.  What steps do I have to take to paste data along with images into the fill-in form entry box in Internet Explorer?

Comment: what is the form for?

Comment: It is a typical fill-in form with a large entry box for our internal company website.

Comment: Does it accept images? Can you insert pictures to it from other tools (e.g. power point, adobe reader)? Can you insert images from Word to other tools (e.g. Excel, Outlook)?

Comment: how do you insert pictures now ?

Comment: No, I can't do simple copy-paste of images.  However, the fill-in form on the webpage has an "insert image" button that will allow me to insert images one-by-one, but this is a cumbersome process.